# Azure Billing when Blobs are not present in storage

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, billing

As we are stopping azure service, we have stopped and deleted the VM's and attached disks last month, which now displays no instances in cloud services, which in turn have deleted the blobs inside the storage. Do we get billed for subscription this month.Any idea?

Comment: No. If you don't have any VMs or blobs holding the VM VHDs, then you will not be charged for those resources. You may get charged for any other resources that you have.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure storage account, your total cost depends on **how much you store**, the volume and type of storage transactions and outbound data transfers, and which data redundancy option you choose.

If you delete all your blobs in your storage account, you don't pay for storage account.

More information about **Azure Storage Pricing** please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).